# D3 Treechart : Text on link(path) in version 4

Tags: d3.js

**Problem**: highlighted text(in the image below) is been over-written(therefore its looking bold) when the node is expanded.

**Expected Output**:
[Collapsible d3 Treechart](http://jsfiddle.net/henbox/82pepd2a/9/)

```
 var linktext = svg.selectAll("g.link")
        .data(links, function (d) {
        console.log("Text Data Id..."+d.id);
        return d.id;
    }); 


    linktext.enter()
    .insert("g")
    .merge(linktext)
    .attr("class", "link")
    .attr("transform", function (d) {
            return "translate(" + ((d.parent.y + d.y) / 2) + "," + ((d.parent.x +d.x) / 2) + ")"; })
    .append("text")
    .attr("dy", ".35em")
    .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
    .text(function (d) {
        debugger;
    console.log("Text Data Rule..."+d.data.rule);
    return d.data.rule;
});
    linktext.exit().transition()
            .remove();
```

[image]

Comment: could you please elaborate the question and also mention what do you need exactly?

Comment: Hi,
The problem is when i expand each nodes then the link text of all prevoius nodes also overwrting thats why its shows like bold letter, but i need to write only the link text of just expanded node

Comment: could you put this into a js fiddle or blockbuilder it would be easier to solve there

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/chamvd05/oL1yrug7/21/

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is caused due to **.merge** function, this code will fix the multiple-element issue

```
var treeData =
    { "name": "E", "children": [{ "name": "A", "rule": "yes", "children": [{ "name": "B", "rule": "<=3.843750000000001", "children": [{ "name": "C", "rule": "yes" }, { "name": "D", "rule": "no", "children": [{ "name": "Sex", "rule": "yes", "children": [{ "name": "E", "rule": "Male", "children": [{ "name": "F", "rule": "<=62.5125" }, { "name": "G", "rule": ">62.5125", "children": [{ "name": "H", "rule": "yes" }, { "name": "K", "rule": "no" }] }] }, { "name": "I", "rule": "Female" }] }, { "name": "J", "rule": "no" }] }] }, { "name": "K", "rule": ">3.843750000000001", "children": [{ "name": "Q", "rule": "yes" }, { "name": "H", "rule": "no", "children": [{ "name": "S", "rule": "yes" }, { "name": "N", "rule": "no" }] }] }] }, { "name": "L", "rule": "no", "children": [{ "name": "S", "rule": "yes", "children": [{ "name": "T", "rule": "<=82.025", "children": [{ "name": "Y", "rule": "<=102.9125" }, { "name": "Malaise", "rule": ">102.9125", "children": [{ "name": "Age", "rule": "no", "children": [{ "name": "J", "rule": ">40.6625", "children": [{ "name": "M", "rule": "yes", "children": [{ "name": "N", "rule": "no", "children": [{ "name": "G", "rule": "yes" }, { "name": "E", "rule": "no" }] }] }] }] }] }] }] }, { "name": "survive", "rule": "no" }] }] };

// Set the dimensions and margins of the diagram
var margin = { top: 20, right: 90, bottom: 30, left: 90 },
    width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

// append the svg object to the body of the page
// appends a 'group' element to 'svg'
// moves the 'group' element to the top left margin
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.right + margin.left)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate("
        + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

var i = 0,
    duration = 750,
    root;

// declares a tree layout and assigns the size
var treemap = d3.tree().size([height, width]);

// Assigns parent, children, height, depth
root = d3.hierarchy(treeData, function (d) { return d.children; });
root.x0 = height / 2;
root.y0 = 0;

// Collapse after the second level
root.children.forEach(collapse);

update(root);

// Collapse the node and all it's children
function collapse(d) {
    if (d.children) {
        d._children = d.children
        d._children.forEach(collapse)
        d.children = null
    }
}

function update(source) {

    // Assigns the x and y position for the nodes
    var treeData = treemap(root);

    // Compute the new tree layout.
    var nodes = treeData.descendants(),
        links = treeData.descendants().slice(1);

    // Normalize for fixed-depth.
    nodes.forEach(function (d) { d.y = d.depth * 180 });

    // ****************** Nodes section ***************************

    // Update the nodes...
    var node = svg.selectAll('g.node')
        .data(nodes, function (d) { return d.id || (d.id = ++i); });

    // Enter any new modes at the parent's previous position.
    var nodeEnter = node.enter().append('g')
        .attr('class', 'node')
        .attr("transform", function (d) {
            return "translate(" + source.y0 + "," + source.x0 + ")";
        })
        .on('click', click);

    // Add Circle for the nodes
    nodeEnter.append('circle')
        .attr('class', 'node')
        .attr('r', 1e-6)
        .style("fill", function (d) {
            return d._children ? "lightsteelblue" : "#fff";
        });

    // Add labels for the nodes
    nodeEnter.append('text')
        .attr("dy", ".35em")
        .attr("x", function (d) {
            return d.children || d._children ? -13 : 13;
        })
        .attr("text-anchor", function (d) {
            return d.children || d._children ? "end" : "start";
        })
        .text(function (d) { return d.data.name; });

    // UPDATE
    var nodeUpdate = nodeEnter.merge(node);

    // Transition to the proper position for the node
    nodeUpdate.transition()
        .duration(duration)
        .attr("transform", function (d) {
            return "translate(" + d.y + "," + d.x + ")";
        });

    // Update the node attributes and style
    nodeUpdate.select('circle.node')
        .attr('r', 10)
        .style("fill", function (d) {
            return d._children ? "lightsteelblue" : "#fff";
        })
        .attr('cursor', 'pointer');


    // Remove any exiting nodes
    var nodeExit = node.exit().transition()
        .duration(duration)
        .attr("transform", function (d) {
            return "translate(" + source.y + "," + source.x + ")";
        })
        .remove();

    // On exit reduce the node circles size to 0
    nodeExit.select('circle')
        .attr('r', 1e-6);

    // On exit reduce the opacity of text labels
    nodeExit.select('text')
        .style('fill-opacity', 1e-6);

    // ****************** links section ***************************

    // Update the links...
    var link = svg.selectAll('path.link')
        .data(links, function (d) { return d.id; });

    // Enter any new links at the parent's previous position.
    var linkEnter = link.enter().insert('path', "g")
        .attr("class", "link")
        .attr('d', function (d) {
            var o = { x: source.x0, y: source.y0 }
            return diagonal(o, o)
        });

    // UPDATE
    var linkUpdate = linkEnter.merge(link);

    // Transition back to the parent element position
    linkUpdate.transition()
        .duration(duration)
        .attr('d', function (d) { return diagonal(d, d.parent) });

    // Remove any exiting links
    link.exit().transition()
        .duration(duration)
        .attr('d', function (d) {
            var o = { x: source.x, y: source.y }
            return diagonal(o, o)
        })
        .remove();


    var linktext = svg.selectAll("g.link")
        .data(links, function (d) {
            return d.id;
        });


    linktext.enter()
        .insert("g")
        //.merge(linktext)
        .attr("class", "link")
        .attr("transform", function (d) {
            return "translate(" + ((d.parent.y + d.y) / 2) + "," + ((d.parent.x + d.x) / 2) + ")";
        })
        .append("text")
        .attr("dy", ".35em")
        .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
        .text(function (d) {
            return d.data.rule;
        });


    linktext.exit().remove();


    // Store the old positions for transition.
    nodes.forEach(function (d) {
        d.x0 = d.x;
        d.y0 = d.y;
    });

    // Creates a curved (diagonal) path from parent to the child nodes
    function diagonal(s, d) {

        path = `M ${s.y} ${s.x}
            C ${(s.y + d.y) / 2} ${s.x},
              ${(s.y + d.y) / 2} ${d.x},
              ${d.y} ${d.x}`

        return path
    }


}

// Toggle children on click.
function click(d) {
    if (d.children) {
        d._children = d.children;
        d.children = null;
    } else {
        d.children = d._children;
        d._children = null;
    }
    update(d);
}
```

Also replace your css with the below to fix the link-text font:

```
.node circle {
  fill: #fff;
  stroke: steelblue;
  stroke-width: 3px;
}

.node text {
  font: 12px sans-serif;
}

path.link {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #000;
  stroke-width: 1px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks , I tried your code, but the issue still persist. when click on each node, the  link text's position is changing. I used this link - https://jsfiddle.net/chamvd05/oL1yrug7/26/